# Linux commandline - auto-optimize pictures

Tags: linux, shell, image-editing

I have a web-app that has very many pictures. Is there a linux commandline utility which I can use to "auto-optimize" all JPEG pictures in a Photoshop-like way. Maybe with Gimp in the backend or so?

Best,
ww

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use ImageMagick - it is a command line tool that allows to do things like image sharpening, contrast stretching or adjusting the gamma level (see the full list here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)